# mouseDragged events get stolen by another view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, nsresponder

I have several views of class `MyView` (subclass of `NSView`) inside another `NSView`. `MyView` implements `-mouseEntered:`, `-mouseExited:`, `-mouseDown:`, `-mouseDragged:`, and `-mouseUp:`.

Almost always, when a `MyView` receives a mouse-down event, all subsequent mouse-dragged events are received by the same `MyView` until the next mouse-up event. Even if the cursor goes outside of the `MyView`. That is the expected behavior.

Occasionally, a `MyView` will receive a mouse-down event, but will only receive mouse-dragged and mouse-up events while the cursor remains inside the `MyView`. If the cursor moves onto a different `MyView`, then that `MyView` starts receiving mouse-dragged events (without first receiving a mouse-down event) and can receive the subsequent mouse-up event.

In case it matters, the mouse-down event creates a `FooView` (subclass of `NSView`) on top of the `MyView`, and the mouse-dragged events resize the frame of the `FooView`. This might be related, as I've only been able to reproduce the problem after one of these `FooView`s has been created. `FooView` does not implement any of the mouse event methods.

I've been messing with this for a while now and haven't been able to either purposely reproduce the problem or recreate the problem in a simple example. I'd be happy to answer any questions about my code, I'm just not sure what would be the relevant part to post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what the root issue is (this Cocoa behavior seems inconsistent to me)...  but here's one possible workaround:

1. In the superview, create an instance variable tracking the `MyView` instance in which the `-mouseDown:` occurred.
2. When you receive a `-mouseDragged:` in `MyView`, instead of operating on `self`, operate on the `MyView` instance reference stored in the superview.

...then you'll be able to consistently track which object is being dragged, without having to run your own event loop.

Comment: The cause of the problem turned out to be NSView not handling overlapping sibling views in a predictable way. Your workaround fixed the problem -- thanks.

Comment: Thank you, this answer just saved me hours of headaches!

Comment: if a child of MyView dissapears (by getting removed or resized) from under the cursor while dragging, things start to go crazy, fast.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run you own mouse tracking loop in the view until mouse is up. You can extend it to process more types of events by passing them into nextEventMatchingMask:.

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent*)event
{
    CGPoint hitPoint = [self pointInViewSpaceFromEvent:event];

    BOOL isDragging = NO;
    BOOL isTracking = YES;

    while (isTracking)
    {       
        switch ([event type])
        {
            case NSLeftMouseDown:
                [self singleMouseDownAtPoint:hitPoint withModifierFlags:[event modifierFlags]];
                break;

            case NSLeftMouseUp:
                isTracking = NO;
                if (isDragging)
                    [self mouseDraggingDidEndAtPoint:hitPoint];
                else
                    [self singleMouseUpAtPoint:hitPoint withEvent:event];
                break;

            case NSLeftMouseDragged:
                if (isDragging)
                    [self mouseDraggingAtPoint:hitPoint withModifierFlags:[event modifierFlags]];
                else
                    isDragging = YES;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (isTracking)
        {
            event = [[self window] nextEventMatchingMask:NSLeftMouseDraggedMask | NSLeftMouseUpMask];
            hitPoint = [self pointInViewSpaceFromEvent:event];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This doesn't exactly fix the problem but maybe it gives a clue. When the mouse-tracking loop is running, the drag and mouse-up events are *not* getting stolen -- presumably because there are no other `MyView`s to steal the event, because the other `MyView`s are blocked from receiving events. However, I don't think the mouse-tracking loop will work for me *because* it blocks all other events. Events to other `MyView`s, and other objects in the application, need to get through. I tried wrapping the loop in a `dispatch_async`, but once again the drag and mouse-up events got stolen.

Comment: If you really need to process dragging events in your view this is the only correct way to do it. This is how all Cocoa controls work. Try to drag the knob of a NSSlider. If it did not track the mouse in its own loop it would stop responding to the drag events as soon as cursor goes out of its bounds. And yes all the events of those types you specify in nextEventMatchingMask: will go to this particular view, other view will not receive them. However, this may be not what you need. If you want to process drags between the views, you need to do it one level up: int the superview of those views.

Comment: What do you mean by "this is the only correct way"? Not that Apple docs are flawless, but the [Cocoa Event-Handling Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingMouseEvents/HandlingMouseEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH6) seems to imply that `mouseDragged` and `mouseUp` should work. Is my problem a bug in Apple's code or my own misunderstanding of how to use it? Note that `mouseDragged` and `mouseUp` *usually* work as I had expected.

Comment: Well, I am sorry, my answer was wrong. You do not need to implement the code I have provided, unless you need more flexibility with events; the window does this job for you calling the methods like mouseDragged:, etc. I have tried to reproduce the case you had described. My guess was that the first responder may be changed during dragging. This might explain why other views start receiving messages. However, I have not managed to reproduce any of those scenarios. I would try to watch becomeFirstResponder and resignFirstResponder in your views. I'm sorry I cannot help without seeing the code.

Comment: so mouseDown gets triggered when there's a NSLeftMouseDragged event or NSLeftMouseUp? I don't get it